# Java: How to display weekday, month and date and no year in locale sensitive manner

Tags: java, datetime, localization

In my app I need to display dates in a locale-sensitive manner. So "Thursday, May 10, 2018" should display as is in en_US but should display as "Thursday, 10 May 2018" in en_GB (English Great Britain).

In most cases I can use the following style of code with java.time API classes:

```
public String toString(ZonedDateTime input) {
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = getDateTimeFormatter(FormatStyle.MEDIUM, FormatStyle.SHORT);
    return input.format(dateTimeFormatter);
}

private DateTimeFormatter getDateTimeFormatter(FormatStyle dateStyle, FormatStyle timeStyle) {
    String pattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
            dateStyle, timeStyle, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, Locale.getDefault());

    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
}
```

In such cases I do not specify an explicit date pattern but instead specify a symbolic FormatStyle.

I am not sure of the best way to handle case where there is no standard FormatStyle that meets my needs.

A concrete example is where I need to show Day of Week, Month and Date but no year.

So "Thursday, May 10, 2018" should display as "Thursday, May 10" in en_US but should display as "Thursday, 10 May" in en_GB (English Great Britain).

Any suggestions on how to handle this requirement?

Comment: So in your example you din’t want the year? I don’t think there’s an easy way through if it’s to work for all thinkable locales.

Comment: Yes don't want the year. Has to work in all locales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String formatPattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
            FormatStyle.FULL, null, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, loc);
    formatPattern = formatPattern.replaceFirst("^.*?([MLdEec].*[MLdEec]).*$", "$1");
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatPattern, loc);
    System.out.println(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Johnston")).format(dateFormatter));
```

Output with `loc` equal to `Locale.US`:

> Thursday, May 10

And with `Locale.UK` (Great Britain):

> Thursday, 10 May

How it works: I start out from a localized format pattern string. In my regular expression I am recognizing format pattern letters that have to do with month (`ML`), day of month (`d`) and day of week (`Eec`). I am keeping the substring from the first to the last of such letters. The leading reluctant quantifier `.*?` makes sure I get the first matching letter. If some locale puts the year somewhere between those wanted elements, it will end up being included.

I am feeling I am being overly creative. Please test with all the test examples you can think of before deciding that you want something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
```

which will use the default system locale. If you want to choose an explicit locale (for testing), then then you can use `withLocale`.

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
    .withLocale(Locale.US);
```

Here's an example:

```
DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
    .withLocale(Locale.US);

System.out.println(
    LocalDate.of(1999, 1, 1).format(pattern)
);
```

Output: `Jan 1, 1999`

If I change the locale to `Locale.UK` the output becomes `1 Jan 1999`

---

To obtain the day of week, you can use

```
DayOfWeek.from(myDate).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault())
```

and then just concatenate the strings. (Again, play with the `Locale` to see different results. `Locale.GERMAN` gives you `Freitag`)

Comment: FYI, another way to localize just the day of week is [`DayOfWeek::getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)). Ex: `LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH )`

Comment: @BasilBourque I prefer that - more control. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to localize the date formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL).withLocale(Locale.US);
```