# JSR310 How to internationalize a pattern for a month-day?

Tags: java, localization, date-formatting, java-time, jsr310

Im trying to format a date without a year (just day and month, e.g **12.10**)

`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)` still yield year for me (12.10.20).

so I tried `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd. MM")` but that obviously **hardcodes order and dot, which wont make american users happy.** (who expect slashes and month first)

How can I internationalize a pattern? Is there some abstract syntax for separators etc?

Comment: This doesn’t answer your question exactly as it stands, but can you adapt the answers to your needs? [Java: How to display weekday, month and date and no year in locale sensitive manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277395/java-how-to-display-weekday-month-and-date-and-no-year-in-locale-sensitive-man) The question and the answers do you JSR-310.

Comment: Please edit your question to make your examples consistent: `12.10` versus `1.1.20`.

Comment: For such a value as your first sentence, you should be using a [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html) object. Unfortunately that class does not work with the `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` formatters to automatically localize. Perhaps you would care to file a feature request on the *java.time* project. This lack has bothered me, but I've never bothered to file a ticket.

Comment: @BasilBourque ok

Comment: It’s not trivial, and I’m not sure we can get every corner case correct. If the built-in format says 12.10.20, would you still want to keep the dot after 10 or not? Probably the best answer differs by locale. The built-in format for Bulgarian is `d.MM.yy 'г'.`, what do we want there? The answer certainly isn’t built-in.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think that a solution can be made that gives 100 % satisfactory results for all locales. Let’s give it a shot anyway.

```
    Locale formattingLocale = Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT);
    String formatPattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
            FormatStyle.SHORT, null, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, formattingLocale);

    // If year comes first, remove it and all punctuation and space before and after it
    formatPattern = formatPattern.replaceFirst("^\\W*[yu]+\\W*", "")
            // If year comes last and is preceded by a space somewhere, break at the space
            // (preserve any punctuation before the space)
            .replaceFirst("\\s\\W*[yu]+\\W*$", "")
            // Otherwise if year comes last, remove it and all punctuation and space before and after it
            .replaceFirst("\\W*[yu]+\\W*$", "");
    DateTimeFormatter monthDayFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatPattern, formattingLocale);
```

For comparison I am printing a date both using the normal formatter with year from your question and using my prepared formatter.

```
    LocalDate exampleDate = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.DECEMBER, 31);
    System.out.format(formattingLocale, "%-11s %s%n",
            exampleDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)),
            exampleDate.format(monthDayFormatter));
```

Output in French locale (`Locale.FRENCH`):

> ```
> 31/12/2020  31/12
> ```

In `Locale.GERMAN`:

> ```
> 31.12.20    31.12
> ```

Edit: My German girl friend informs me that this is wrong. We should always write a dot after each of the two numbers because both are ordinal numbers. Meno Hochschild, the German author of the other answer, also produces `31.12.` with two dots for German.

In `Locale.US`:

> ```
> 12/31/20    12/31
> ```

It might make American users happy. In Swedish (`Locale.forLanguageTag("sv")`):

> ```
> 2020-12-31  12-31
> ```

In a comment I mentioned Bulgarian (`bg`):

> ```
> 31.12.20 г. 31.12
> ```

As far as I have understood, “г.” (Cyrillic g and a dot) is an abbreviation of a word that means *year*, so when leaving out the year, we should probably leave this abbreviation out too. I’m in doubt whether we ought to include the dot after 12.

Finally Hungarian (`hr`):

> ```
> 31. 12. 2020. 31. 12.
> ```

How the code works: We are first inquiring `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` about the short date format pattern for the locale. I assume that this is the pattern that your formatter from the question is also using behind the scenes (haven’t checked). I then use different regular expressions to remove the year from different variants, see the comments in the code. Year may be represented by `y` or `u`, so I take both into account (in practice `y` is used). Now it’s trivial to build a new formatter from the modified pattern. For the Bulgarian: from my point of view there is an error in Java regular expressions, they don’t recognize Cyrillic letters as word characters, which is why г was removed too (the error is in documentation too, it claims that a word character is `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`).
We were lucky, though, in our case it produces the result that I wanted.

If you’re happy with a 90 % solution, this would be my suggestion, and I hope you can modify it to any needs your users in some locale may have.

**Link:** [Documentation of Java regular expressions (regex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as Ole pointed out there is no 100% satisfying solution using `java.time` only. But my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) has found a solution based on the data of the CLDR repository (ICU4J also gives support) using the type [AnnualDate](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/AnnualDate.html) (as replacement for `MonthDay`):

```
LocalDate yourLocalDate = ...;
MonthDay md = MonthDay.from(yourLocalDate);
AnnualDate ad = AnnualDate.from(md);

ChronoFormatter<AnnualDate> usStyle =
  ChronoFormatter.ofStyle(DisplayMode.SHORT, Locale.US, AnnualDate.chronology());
ChronoFormatter<AnnualDate> germanStyle =
  ChronoFormatter.ofStyle(DisplayMode.SHORT, Locale.GERMANY, AnnualDate.chronology());
System.out.println("US-format: " + usStyle.format(ad)); // US-format: 12/31
System.out.println("German: " + germanStyle.format(ad)); // German: 31.12.
```

Comment: @OleV.V. That was a typo. I have corrected it. The dot in German format corresponds to CLDR data but is optional in my opinion (as I am a German).

Comment: Aus Neugier, are the localized formats for month-day/annual date included ready-made in [CLDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository)?

Comment: @OleV.V.Yes, ready-made in CLDR (but not included in `java.time`, Oracle is sometimes very slow although there is a very old similar [issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8168532) with the same root cause.